# Deserializing JSON object into a C# list

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a given JSON file in C# using a [tutorial by Bill Reiss](http://www.billreiss.com/making-json-web-requests-easier-with-async-and-await/). For XML data in a non-list this method works pretty well, though I would like to deserialize a JSON file with the following structure:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Att1 { get; set; }
    public string Att2 { get; set; }
    public string Att3 { get; set; }
    public string Att4 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{

public List<Data> Listname { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is with using JSON.Net's ability to create / put data into lists, and then displaying the list on an XAML page. My idea so far (which is not working):

```
var resp = await client.DoRequestJsonAsync<DATACLASS>("URL");
string t = resp.ToString();
var _result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DATACLASS>>(t);
XAMLELEMENT.ItemsSource = _result;
```

Comment: It is not clear what your actual problem is yet.  What is `DATACLASS`?

Comment: I'm sorry! The Problem is that my code is not working (Debugger.Break()). DATACLASS is the "class Data" described above. (I'm sorry for this confusing Name. You can take it as "Data")

Comment: I was talking about RootObject - not Data! Data defines the elements, RootObject the list itself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So I think you're probably trying to deserialize to the wrong type.  If you serialized it to RootObject and try to deserialize to List it's going to fail.

See this example code

```
public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>
                        {
                            new Item { Att1 = "ABC", Att2 = "123" }, 
                            new Item { Att1 = "EFG", Att2 = "456" }, 
                            new Item { Att1 = "HIJ", Att2 = "789" }
                        };
        var root = new Root() { Items = items };
        var itemsSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
        var rootSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);

        //This works
        var deserializedItemsFromItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(itemsSerialized); 

        //This works
        var deserializedRootFromRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(rootSerialized); 

        //This will fail.  YOu serialized it as root and tried to deserialize as List<Item>
        var deserializedItemsFromRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(rootSerialized);

        //This will fail also for the same reason 
        var deserializedRootFromItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(itemsSerialized);
    }

class Root
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; } 
}

class Item
{
    public string Att1 { get; set; }
    public string Att2 { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Added complete code.

Comment: I tried your code. I added the following lines in order to Display it. Do you see the mistake (it's  not working. No Error just no change)?

    string t = deserializedItemsFromItems.ToString();
    PhoneList.ItemsSource = t;
    string v = deserializedRootFromRoot.ToString();
    PhoneList.ItemsSource = v;

Comment: The code above wouldn't work out the the box as soon as it hits var deserializedItemsFromRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(rootSerialized); it's going to throw an exception.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the deserialization or assigning ItemsSource?  Assuming you get an deserialized object back then something.ItemsSource = Root.Items.ToList(); should work.

Comment: Thank you so much cgotberg. It's finally working! Your "ToList" - Hint made it.