# c# json List deserialization

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, deserialization

Having below classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestDynamicJSON1
{
    public TestDynamicJSON1()
    {
        this.TO2_List = new List<TestDynamicJSON2>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int A { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string B { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime C { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<TestDynamicJSON2> TO2_List { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestDynamicJSON2
{
    public TestDynamicJSON2()
    {

    }

    [DataMember]
    public int A2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string B2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime C2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestDynamicJSON2_1 : TestDynamicJSON2
{
    public TestDynamicJSON2_1()
    {

    }

}

[DataContract]
public class TestDynamicJSON2_2 : TestDynamicJSON2
{
    public TestDynamicJSON2_2()
    {

    }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestDynamicJSON2_3 : TestDynamicJSON2
{
    public TestDynamicJSON2_3()
    {

    }
}
```

At server side converting objects into JObject:

```
public JObject GetDynamicJO()
        {
            TestDynamicJSON1 TO = new Metadata.CatalogManagement.TestDynamicJSON1();

            TO.A = 1;
            TO.B = "2";
            TO.C = DateTime.Now;

            TestDynamicJSON2_1 TO2_1 = new Metadata.CatalogManagement.TestDynamicJSON2_1();

            TO2_1.A2 = 11;
            TO2_1.B2 = "22";
            TO2_1.C2 = DateTime.Now;

            TO.TO2_List.Add(TO2_1);

            TestDynamicJSON2_2 TO2_2 = new Metadata.CatalogManagement.TestDynamicJSON2_2();

            TO2_2.A2 = 11;
            TO2_2.B2 = "22";
            TO2_2.C2 = DateTime.Now;

            TO.TO2_List.Add(TO2_2);


            TestDynamicJSON2_3 TO2_3 = new Metadata.CatalogManagement.TestDynamicJSON2_3();

            TO2_3.A2 = 11;
            TO2_3.B2 = "22";
            TO2_3.C2 = DateTime.Now;

            TO.TO2_List.Add(TO2_3);


            JProperty property1 = new JProperty("DO", JToken.FromObject(TO));
            JObject jo = new JObject(property1);

            return jo;
        }
```

At client side trying to deserialize:

```
var str = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var jo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestDynamicJSON1>(str);
```

Json string is as below:

```
{"DO":{"A":1,"B":"2","C":"2015-12-24T19:42:51.6509893+04:00","TO2_List":[{"A2":11,"B2":"22","C2":"2015-12-24T19:42:51.6509893+04:00"},{"A2":11,"B2":"22","C2":"2015-12-24T19:42:51.6509893+04:00"},{"A2":11,"B2":"22","C2":"2015-12-24T19:42:51.6509893+04:00"}]}}
```

And the list TO2_List property is empty. Is it because of it is list of BaseClass?

Could you pls help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your json string look like?

Comment: Sorry, I updated question, in fact problem is that TO2_List is property is empty. In fact there should 3 objects.

Comment: Those class names are VERY confusing.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. There is no JSON in your question, so we can't verify what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As I am beginner for WebApi and Json, my class names are for testing purpose only. Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json deserialize list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019729/json-deserialize-list)

Answer (score 1):

your class should be like this.

```
public class TO2List
{
     public int A2 { get; set; }
     public string B2 { get; set; }
     public string C2 { get; set; }
}

public class DO
{
     public int A { get; set; }
     public string B { get; set; }
     public string C { get; set; }
     public List<TO2List> TO2_List { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public DO DO { get; set; }
}
```

you bind value this way.

```
var str = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var jo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str);
```

and you get value this way

```
//jo.DO.A
```