# json file read from c# code

Tags: c#, json

This is my json file

```
{
  "UseCase1": {
    "UseCaseId": "Usecase1",
    "UseCaseDescription": "description1"

},
"UseCase2": {
    "UseCaseId": "Usecase2",
    "UseCaseDescription": "description2"

}

}
```

This is my class

```
public class UseCase
    {
        public string UseCaseId { get; set;}
        public string UseCaseDescription { get; set;}
    }
```

How to assign the json elements to a list of this class(UseCase)

I tried the below code, but it is not working

```
string Json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\ENERGY METER\ENERGY METER –IRP\SourceCode\EDMI.EnergyMeterPOC\EDMI.EnergyMeterPOC.Repository\DataSource\UseCaseData.json");
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var personlist = ser.Deserialize<List<UseCase>>(Json);
            return personlist;
```

Comment: newtonsoft json deserialize list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019729/json-deserialize-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297563/read-and-parse-a-json-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does `N` in `UseCaseN` keep increasing, do you want to support an unlimited collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at your Json again.

When placed into a tool like [JSON Utils](http://jsonutils.com/), you end up with the following.

```
public class UseCase1
{
    public string UseCaseId { get; set; }
    public string UseCaseDescription { get; set; }
}

public class UseCase2
{
    public string UseCaseId { get; set; }
    public string UseCaseDescription { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public UseCase1 UseCase1 { get; set; }
    public UseCase2 UseCase2 { get; set; }
}
```

In order for your object to be in a list it woudl first have to be an array which your file is not.

You Json file would have to be looking like this to satisfy your `UseCase` collection requirement

```
{
  "UseCases": [
  {
    "UseCaseId": "Usecase1",
    "UseCaseDescription": "description1"
  },
  {
    "UseCaseId": "Usecase2",
    "UseCaseDescription": "description2"
  }]
}
```

which would have the following classes when deserialized...

```
public class UseCase
{
    public string UseCaseId { get; set; }
    public string UseCaseDescription { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<UseCase> UseCases { get; set; }
}
```